# Issue on Adding Fade In Effect to Raphaël.js Image Element

Tags: javascript, raphael

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/oof81u99/1/) and let me know why I am not able to add Fadein function to image element of the Raphaël.js  paper?

```
var r = new Raphael(10,10, 500, 500);
var c = r.circle(200, 200, 80);

var img = r.image("http:/.../123.png", 100, 105, 200, 200).animate({ opacity : 1 }, 3000);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fade it in fine, you just need to have the opacity to 0 el.attr({ opacity: 0 }) in the first place for it to fade to...

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oof81u99/2/)

```
var img = r.image("http://www.eatyourcareer.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/ok-256x2561.png", 100, 105, 200, 200)
           .attr({ opacity: 0 })
           .animate({ opacity : 1 }, 3000);
```